# Get tweets from public without authentication

Tags: javascript, json, twitter

I am trying to make a twitter telegram bot.
I need the get the tweets from an account (not mine) as JSON or something like that.

Because I don't want all the tweets to send to my telegram bot but only the ones containing a certain string. So I will loop through the JSON last tweet and only send it to the bot when needed)

Now the things is I cant get any twitter feed within my code, I also tried the Twitter API but no succes. I am reading some articles about twitter updated their API and its no longer possible to get twitter feed without owning the account and having the auth tokens.

Please let me know if I still can get twitter feeds with Javascript?

Comment: Have you check twitters api documentation? Seems like little research here.

Comment: Yeah I have done that. A little while ago you could still get tweets from almost every account without AUTH. Now (how I read it) is you need to have access to the AUTH keys to get tweets from a Twitter account.